# Calling lists.asmx Webservices using Script out of sharepoint environment

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, soap, windows-desktop-gadgets

I want to use List.asmx getallitems webservice to get all the list items in a windows 7 gadget, I have been doing research for last 10 days,but couldn't really find what i want.

Keeping in mind, there's hundred tutorial I find on google that are doing same thing but for Sharepoint 2010 or web content webpart, or by using .Net web reference or proxy.

problem here is, I am using Sharepoint 2007 and I want to develop a Windows 7 gadget for clients so it will be out of sharepoint environment and because its a Windows 7 gadget, so all  tools i got hold of are,

- HTML
- Scripting language JavaScript/Jquery
- SOAP to call webservices
- CAML query maybe ?
- XMLHTTPRequest ? but then our portal is on SSL/HTTPS

Oh one thing I forgot to mention, I need to do Windows authentication as well, so i can't just directly write a SOAP message to get the list items. so Webservices I can play with are "lists.asmx" and "authentication.asmx"

**Additional Information**

Our sharepoint is currently accessible by Ipad and what they are doing is, authenticating the user somehow and getting a cookie in return, and use it for later validations and operations, how to do that ? i got no clue at all. I can't ask them for help either well at least for the moment.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford deploying a COM component with your gadget, you can have a look at [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10651437/623816). You can reuse the authenticated Windows session when calling an SP WS from your .NET CCW DLL.

--- Ferda

Comment: Hi Ferdianand, am bit confused now, is it possible if we can chat somewhere on this topic please ?